# asp.net mvc3 server benchmark tools

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, benchmarking, cpu

I am using IIS6 / 7.5 . MVC3 . I am going to do some re factoring in the code. I want to measure CPU cycles. Which may be affected by using DI or passing a model down the line, like a factory DI pattern.

Does anyone know any good tools or techniques available for this purpose? Thanks.